# Robust regression in scilab

Tags: optimization, linear-regression, scilab, estimation

For the aim of a robust linear regression, i want to realize a M-Estimator with Geman-McLure loss function

[image]

The class of M-Estimators are presented in [this document](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kyros/courses/2503/Handouts/robustEstimation.pdf) and Geman-McLure can be found at page 13.
To solve the minimization problem, [Iteratively reweighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) is recommended. How can i implement this procedure in [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)? May i use `optim`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the site of the document](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kyros/courses/2503) you linked there are also some [Matlab demo files available in a zip](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kyros/courses/2503/Handouts/matlabVisTools.zip). There are two files in this zip that I think are important:

- utvisToolbox/tutorials/lineTut/robustDemo.m
- utvisToolbox/tutorials/lineTut/robustIteration.m

In the robustDemo.m file there is a implementation of the **Robust M-estimation Algorithm**.

To answer your question how to implement this in SciLab; You could start by converting these matlab files to scilab using [`mfile2sci`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/mfile2sci.html). At least in the 
`sampleRobustObj` and `robustIteration` functions, only basic Matlab stuff is used which should be convertible by `mfile2sci`.